# How to use a system color in a lineargradientbrush in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a gradient background for my window

```
<Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
```

I would like to replace the black gradient stop with the system color for control faces (the color buttons and dialog boxes are by default)

Whats the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a Color through the static-extension:

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColor}" />
```