# How can I use a system color for gradients in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to have a sytem color from a theme as part of a `LinearGradientBrush` in Windows Phone. So instead of

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardGradientBackground"  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF660000" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFff0033" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I'd like to use something like

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardGradientBackground"  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="SystemColors.ActiveBorderColor" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFff0033" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I tried different syntaxes and also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375090/how-to-use-a-system-color-in-a-lineargradientbrush-in-wpf), but `"static is not supported in a Windows App Project"` as Visual Studio says.

I also tried to achieve the same programmatically

```
LinearGradientBrush linearGradientBrush =
    new LinearGradientBrush
    {
        StartPoint = new Point( 0.5, 0.5 ),
        EndPoint = new Point( 0.5, 1 )
    };
Color currentAccentColorHex = (Color)Current.Resources[ "PhoneAccentColor" ];
linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( new GradientStop
{
    Color = currentAccentColorHex,
    Offset = 0
} );
linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( new GradientStop
{
    Color = Colors.Black,
    Offset = 1
} );
```

As soon as I get to the line where I try to access (Application.)Current.Resources I end up with a `System.Exception` with `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`.

Any ideas?

**Update**

I'm trying to set this in the `App.xaml` (respectively `App.xaml.cs` for the programmatic approach) file, just in case that would mean to take any special steps into account.

Comment: Have you tried [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351215/get-phoneaccentcolor-in-window-phone-8-1windows-runtime-app#comment37650863_24351564)? : `((SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color`

Comment: @har Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I end up with the same result though. The cast won't happen until accessing `Current.Resources` went okay, so the cause is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SystemColorControlAccentColor}" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFff0033" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 underlines the Color attribute and the tooltip shows `The resource "SystemColorControlAccentColor" could not be resolved` - trying `ThemeResource` instead of `StaticResource` doesn't work either. I'm trying to set this in the `App.xaml` file.

Comment: It's for WP8.1 (works for W8.1 too) but I didn't test it in VS2015. It works in VS2013 though. Maybe in VS2015 there is another "modern" syntax.

Comment: BTW did you try to just compile this code? VS2013 doesn't underline it but IntelliSense doesn't propose it either. It might compile so just give it a try.

Comment: You're right, I assumed it wouldn't work as VS2015 underlined it with the error message stated above. Strange behaviour, would be better if it wouldn't indicate an error when it actually works. Thank you :)